# My question was closed by somebody because Dottard commented that it was silly

Tags: discussion

The question is "If Jesus is the Almighty God, Is the account in Luke 22:41-43 consistent with him being Almighty? 
Luke 22:41-43, of the Berean Study Bible says:

41And He withdrew about a stone’s throw beyond them, where He knelt down and prayed, 42“Father, if You are willing, take this cup from Me. Yet not My will, but Yours be done." 43Then an angel from heaven appeared to Him and strengthened Him.

Does the Almighty God need to pray to be strengthened? If Jesus is Almighty like the Father and the Father is not more powerful than the Son, why does the Son pray to the Father?

What is silly with this question? [Here is the link to the question.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47257/if-jesus-is-the-almighty-god-is-the-account-in-luke-2241-43-consistent-with-hi?noredirect=1#comment92663_47257)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The definition of the Community is as follows:

> **Biblical Hermeneutics**
>
> Q&A for professors, theologians, and those interested in exegetical
>   analysis of biblical texts

it does not say:

"no biblical Questions"

It also does not say:

"no doctrine Questions"

This website will have a doctrinal bias obviously. To remove doctrine is to remove God himself from the Bible.

The people that Closed your Question need to be removed from their postions on this website.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: This answer doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: You say "*it does not say 'no biblical questions'*" and "*It also does not say 'no doctrine questions'*".  True, but it also doesn't say "no questions about James Bond", but most people realize that asking about James Bond would be inappropriate here.  But it *does* say "exegetical analysis of biblical texts", a topic that excludes doctrine and faith.

Comment: You say "*This website will have a doctrinal bias obviously.*", but what should be obvious is that this site is intended to *not* have any doctrinal bias. And "*To remove doctrine is to remove God himself from the Bible.*" is in many ways part of the reason for this site's existence.

Comment: And actually, it *does* explicitly say "*Don't ask about Christian doctrine*".  You (and Alex) should take the [Tour - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: There are no 'positions' on the website apart from Moderators. It is a _community_.

Answer (score 5):

The question isn't silly, but it *is* inappropriate for this site, which is for questions about interpretation, not doctrine. Christianity.SE would be more appropriate.

And the question should be directed to specific denominations, as different groups will have different interpretations of this scripture.

E.g. something like "*For those denominations that believe that Jesus was still fully divine while incarnated, how do they resolve the apparent conflict between … ?*"

Comment: I thought Hermeneutics is applied to questions of general interpretations and that it is the art of understanding and of making oneself understood.

Comment: @AlexBalilo, the site is for objective interpretations, which in theory are free of doctrinal bias.  Ideally, the questions and answers could be something looked up in a secular encyclopedia, with answers provided by atheists.  Doctrinal interpretations belong in Christianity.SE, though again, the questions should be worded so they could be answered by an atheistic expert.  Asking "is Jesus equal to the Father" is called "off-topic"; asking "do Catholics believe that Jesus is equal to the Father" is appropriate.

Comment: I see comments, questions and answers using the trinity, which is a doctrine, and yet are not flagged as silly or off topic. Why is a question that seeks clarity to that trinity be off topic?

Comment: @AlexBalilo, the questions in Hereneutics.SE, are like [Does the Greek of John 20:28 address two persons or one?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/does-the-greek-of-john-2028-address-two-persons-or-one), which asks about Greek grammar, not about religious beliefs, and those in Christianity.SE, are like [history - Did early church fathers understand the doctrine of trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8958/did-early-church-fathers-understand-the-doctrine-of-trinity), which asks about historical religion, not about what we should believe.

Comment: My question is about interpretation.

Comment: @AlexBalilo, but you are asking for a specific doctrinal interpretation, and in the wrong site.  Consider a secular situation: Archimedes said "δῶς μοι πᾶ στῶ καὶ τὰν γᾶν κινάσω"; *Could his "move the earth" be reasonably interpreted as simply moving a lump of soil?* would be appropriate for hermeneutics, while *Did his followers believe him capable of such an action?* would be appropriate for the equivalent of the Christianity.SE site.  Neither require any faith or belief on the part of the answerer.  But your *Did God need to pray?* requires that the answerer believe that God exists.

Comment: @RayButterworth why are you even an admin here? This is "BIBLICAL" one cannot exclude doctrine studies from a site like this. You are a mod in the wrong site.

Comment: @DeerSpotter, I am not an "admin" or "mod".  I was simply explaining (perhaps in vain) why this question was inappropriate here.

Comment: So, unless it pertains to Greek grammar, the question is considered inappropriate? Isn't all that learning suppose to make the bible clearly understood ? If the true identity of  the God of the Bible is not that easy to  perceive and If God presented himself like a puzzle that needs assembly, shouldn't a site like Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange help in  finding Him ? Are comments that say: "that's a silly question" allowed but not a question like my question,  which you say is not silly, is not?

Comment: @AlexBalilo, my answer began with "*The question *isn't* silly*", and I don't think it would be appropriate to call it that even if it were.  So yes, I agree with you on that.

Comment: @AlexBalilo, one uses Hermeneutics.SE to get a scholarly answer agreeing that Greek word XXX could be used to mean AAA or BBB, but never CCC. Then, uses that authoritative fact to ask a question in Christianity.SE: "*Given that XXX can not legitimately be translated as CCC, how does denomination JJJ justify their belief that …?*".  Note that in neither question is there any assumption of any religious belief or position on the part of the people that will answer it.  The questions and answers are objective and secular; personal beliefs and opinions are inappropriate except in comments.

Comment: @AlexBalilo, I now notice that the original "silly" comment has been removed.